# Find normal of a plane by given then intersection line and the normal of another Plane

Tags: plane

Normally Intersection of two planes A and B (not parallel) will return a line L. I know how to implement this, but if now given a plane A and the line of intersection L to find plane B. Is there a solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to find (or "recover") the plane B, because an infinite number of planes (Bs) can intersect plane A exactly at the line L but still are allowed to "hinge" (or rotate) about it (within certain limits of course so as to not be parallel as you mention).

You need a little bit more information to define one single plane (three points, a point and a line, a point and a normal vector, for more information please [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Line_of_intersection_between_two_planes)). Also, [Paul Bourke's website](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/) contains really a wealth of information if you are working in computer graphics.

Perhaps there is a way to get this little bit of information from your problem (?)

(By the way, i am not sure that this a question for Stackoverflow, perhaps it would fit better to the Mathematics part)

Comment: I have plane A which define by 3 points (a triangle) and an intersection line L(two 3D Points). Plane A is always perpendicular to axis-Z (0,0,1), the plane B(unknown plane) has a constant slope to the x-y plane(meaning that plane B can only rotate around the axis-Z). Any hope to find plane B. Thanks!

Comment: Then:
1) A is well defined with 3 XY points (to be perpendicular to the Z axis).
2) L exists on this XY plane (since it's the line that is defined by the intersection of A and B)

Which means that your B must be passing through L (which is known) and be parallel to a vector in the Z-Axis direction.

(Then, this "plane B can only rotate around the axis-Z" can be calculated by taking the slope of L in the XY plane 
(do i get your description correctly?))

(Also, if it is possible to share more about your actual problem there might be an alternative / easier way to deal with it)

Comment: B plane is not parallel to a vector in the Z-Axis direction. For example, B (unknown plane) could be a define by 3 points P1(0,0,0),P2(1,0,0),P3(1,1,1). In this case the angle between vector P3-P2 and plane X-Y is 45 degree. My problem is plane B could rotate about the Z-Axis only and the angle between vector P3-P2 and Plane X-Y is  always a constant value(in this example is 45). The Plane A and line L are known, only Plane B is unknown (but will always fulfill the condition I mention previously). Hope I make myself clear about this situation. Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is more or less what i have in mind with the exception that your L is fixed for a given "fit". In other words, A is known to be on the XY plane. Two points on A define L. Now B must go through L but where does it "rest" on the other side? You must have an extra condition, an extra bit of information. Otherwise, B is allowed to "hinge" around L. 
(More generally, you can check if your problem fits in one of the standard cases of defining a plane from the link i am providing in the answer.)

Comment: Maybe I should make the case simpler, now just ignore about plane A. Given a Line L, and Plane B has a constant slope to a plane X-Y (use the 3 points example  P1(0,0,0),P2(1,0,0),P3(1,1,1)). Plane  B can only be rotated about the axis-Z, I need to rotate plane B about the axis-Z so that the Line L will lie on the plane B (distance of start and end point of line L from plane B is zero. Hope this much clearer now, thanks for spending time with this problem.

Comment: Let's fix a few things. Looking at the screen, X extends to the right, Y extends upwards and Z extends inwards. The line L is given. Therefore B's space will have to coincide with it. If this is the case, then B can only rotate ABOUT L (the hinging i am referring to). If you have to constrain B but still transform it so that it coincides with the line L, then this might be a different problem. That's why i am asking, what is it the actual problem you are trying to solve originally (of which, this plane intersection is just a sub problem of)